# Android create myApp:// protocol that will launch my app

Tags: android

I've seen in some application like [Waze - GPS Navigation](http://www.waze.com) and Facebook app have a protocol that when the user surf to a waze:// site, it opens the Waze app with a given location.

For example:

When i have Waze installed in my phone and i'm surfing to:

```
waze://?ll=<lat>,<lon>
```

The Waze application will automatically opens and center my map to lat,lan location.

How can i make and register a protocol to my own app that will use syntax like

```
`myApp://command`
```

and will open my application with a given parameters ?

Comment: As far as registering custom intents goes, see http://openintents.org

Comment: @CommonsWare - is it posiible to make a schema that incase the user doesn't have the app it will send him to download in the Google's market ?

Comment: If you want you app beeing compatible with other apps you should also look at  [openintents-uris](http://www.openintents.org/en/uris). Additional to @EdwardFalk-s comment this site also defines uri schema . There are already uris for "geo:" and "google.navigation:ll=latitude,longitude"

Answer (score 1):

> is it posiible to make a schema that incase the user doesn't have the app it will send him to download in the Google's market ?

No.

You are welcome to use an HTTP URL as your "custom protocol":

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="www.this-so-does-not-exist.com"
                android:path="/something"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

This `<intent-filter>` will match `http://www.this-so-does-not-exist.com/something`. If your app is not installed, the user will view this in a Web browser. However, if your app *is* installed, the user might still elect to view this in a Web browser, rather than choose your app from the chooser.